How to find the best matching CMYK color for this color?
Does anyone have an idea how to find the best matching CMYK color for digital print for this mint green color?

HEX: #8BFF85
RGB: 140/255/133

Thanks for your help!!!

What is the printing method? More advanced inkjets might come close

My computer is decently calibrated, so, as I see it that color is most likely not possible on CMYK. So you need to explore using spot ink, probably a fluorescent one.
If you want to explore spot inks, you need a Pantone Color Guide, the Forluma Guide.

For a digital print, the most you can do is print a series of swatches and choose the one you like the most. You need to do this on the specific printer you will be using.
On a digital printer, Inkjet or laser, you will normally have brighter colors keeping the file RGB.
Use this file I made and print an initial sample. Keep it as a reference.
https://otake.com.mx/Color/RGB-01-Letter-LowRes.png

You can based on that initial sample make another file with smaller changes on different swatches.


It's already said in comments: This color is not achievable by inserting CMYK inks on white paper and watching it in somehow usual light. The used term was "It's out of the gamut of most CMYK printing processes". I didn't find one even close in the CMYK print process color profile collection of Photoshop.
Of course, I cannot say anything of systems which print on super-reflective aluminium material and maybe use more inks than the four CMYK.
Making this color by printing it on a white paper with a CMYK print process is possible. Only direct a bright enough white light to the print, substantially brighter than the usual light environment. But it's not practical and the new process must be adjusted by making experiments. If it MUST be printed check if it's available as a spot color. Your printer will tell.
